# Is there a Google plus API to check if a person has added me into to his circle

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Is there a Google API to check if a person has added me into his circle? I checked the google plus api list and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

No but you can [star this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=9).